# Making a more efficient monte carlo simulation

Tags: performance, r, statistics, simulation

So, I've written this code that should effectively estimate the area under the curve of the function defined as h(x). My problem is that i need to be able to estimate the area to within 6 decimal places, but the algorithm i've defined in estimateN seems to be using too heavy for my machine. Essentially the question is how can i make the following code more efficient? Is there a way i can get rid of that loop?

```
h = function(x) {
    return(1+(x^9)+(x^3))
}
estimateN = function(n) {
    count = 0
    k = 1
    xpoints = runif(n, 0, 1)
    ypoints = runif(n, 0, 3)
    while(k <= n){
    if(ypoints[k]<=h(xpoints[k]))
        count = count+1
    k = k+1
    }
    #because of the range that im using for y
    return(3*(count/n))
}
#uses the fact that err<=1/sqrt(n) to determine size of dataset
estimate_to = function(i) {
    n = (10^i)^2
    print(paste(n, " repetitions: ", estimateN(n)))
}

estimate_to(6)
```

Comment: `estimate_to(6)` might be a little too greedy: your current algorithm  will likely make R run out of memory trying to allocate numeric vectors of length 1e12.

Comment: If you really need 1e12 simulations, you'll have to rewrite your algorithm so it finds a compromise between computation times and memory usage.

Comment: The best way to make Monte Carlo integration (much) more efficient, i.e. get the same precision within less iterations, is to use importance sampling, for example Metropolis Monte Carlo. In your case points with `x` closer to `1.0` contribute more to the value of the integral than those closer to `0.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
count = 0
k = 1
while(k <= n){
if(ypoints[k]<=h(xpoints[k]))
    count = count+1
k = k+1
}
```

With this line:

```
count <- sum(ypoints <= h(xpoints))
```

Comment: I think that sums up the power of vectorization pretty eloquently.

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly efficiency you're striving for, `integrate` is several orders of magnitude faster (not to mention more memory efficient) for this problem.

```
integrate(h, 0, 1)

# 1.35 with absolute error < 1.5e-14

microbenchmark(integrate(h, 0, 1), estimate_to(3), times=10)

# Unit: microseconds
#                expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#  integrate(h, 0, 1)     14.456     17.769     42.918     54.514     83.125    10
#      estimate_to(3) 151980.781 159830.956 162290.668 167197.742 174881.066    10
```